# Failed to spawn ngrokpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: ngrok

i am trying to run an azure bot locally.
I installed ngrok and Bot Framework Emulator.
I downloaded the source code, editet the .bot file to use the endpoint that is displayed in the ngrok command window, ran it in VS 2017 community and opened it in the framework emulator. But then i got this:

[image: error]

Comment: Same issue. No idea what is going on.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes restarting the bot emulator helps. I have the same issue sometimes, but I don't know the cause.

The bot emulator feels a bit unreliable in general.